# Can't start gunicorn.service on VirtualBox with CentOS 8, Nginx and Django-Rest-Framework

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, centos, gunicorn

Trying to deploy django application using gunicorn and nginx on CentOS. Following DigitalOcean tutorial: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7

But I have CentOS 8.

I can run my application locally from virtualenv using:

```
python manage.py runserver

gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app.wsgi:application
```

but then I try to run gunicorn.service I have status - failed.

Inside of systemctl status gunicorn.service I have

```
started gunicorn deamon
gunicorn.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
gunicorn.service: failed with result 'exit-code'
```

Without  this file I can't bind app.sock file as it not being created.

My gunicorn.service looks like this
app - is fictional application name :)
admin - is a real user of this system

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=admin
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/admin/app/portal/app
ExecStart=/home/admin/app/env/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/admin/app/portal/app/app.sock app.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

There is a tree of my project:
app

```
- env
- portal
-- client
-- app
--- documents
--- fixtures
--- images
--- app
---- __init__.py
---- settings.py
---- urls.py
---- wsgi.py
--- app_project
---- ...
--- manage.py
--- requirements.txt
```

What can be done to make it work and that can I check to find more clues why it doesn't work?

Any input is welcome.

Thanks

---

in journalctl -xe
I've noticed
`SELinux is preventing file/path from execute access on the file`
so I changed 
`SELINUX=permissive`
in /etc/selinux/config

rebooted and now I have different error in systemctl status gunicorn.service:

```
gunicorn: error: unrecognized arguments: app.wsgi:application
```

oh, that was because I added additional flag to ExecStart. Removed it and it works now.

So issue was with SELinux.

Will keep it here in case if it would be useful to anyone